# How to keep iterating through divs until you reach a div with a certain class

Tags: jquery, css

So I have html that looks like this:

```
<div class="parent"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="parent"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>

....
```

Basically what I want to do is when `.parent` is clicked, toggle `display: none` to all `.child` between the `.parent` clicked, and the next `.parent`. So say I click on the first `.parent`, I want to toggle `display: none` to the 4 `.childs` in between the two parents. How would I do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`.nextUntil()` method](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) in order to select the sibling elements *until* the next `.parent` element:

```
$('.parent').on('click', function () {
  $(this).nextUntil('.parent').toggle();
});
```

Here is a basic example:

```js
$('.parent').on('click', function() {
  $(this).nextUntil('.parent').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">parent</div>
<div class="child">child</div>
<div class="child">child</div>
<div class="child">child</div>
<div class="child">child</div>
<div class="parent">parent</div>
<div class="child">child</div>
<div class="child">child</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is right, but can you tell me how I can adjust it so instead of `.nextUntil('.parent')`, it's nextUntil the div **without** `.child`? Because at the moment instead of  `<div class="child"></div>` it's `<div class="parent child"></div>`

Comment: @Zorgan - In that case it sounds like you want `.nextUntil('.parent:not(.child)')`. Here is a [basic example demonstrating the usage](https://jsfiddle.net/8n1g81x1/), feel free to edit.